# Parts needed to run Geoserver/PostGIS from a program like Microsoft Access

Tags: geoserver, google-earth, ms-access, getmap

I have a fair bit of experience in GIS and Python, but am brand new to developing on the web.

I have rented some space on a server and have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database as well as Geoserver on it.  The other side of the coin is a Microsoft Access database (which will later be a web based application, but that's later) that has a bunch of data related to the Spatial data (polygon layers) up on the server.

What components do I need to develop so that the Access database can request specific data from Geoserver and have it display on a webpage (that is seen by the user through the Access program).  I also want the Access program to be able to request a KML layer that will display in Google Earth.

For the first option I think that I need to use the OpenLayers GetMap examples and build a map from that.  The map will need to be able to get all of a particular layer, as well as one polygon from the same layer displayed differently so that it stands out.  I remember that there is a way to integrate Google Maps as a base layer.  Are there other/better options?

For the second option (use the Access database to query Geoserver and display the result in Google Earth) I'm at a loss.  It seems like it can be done, but how?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction as most of these technologies are new to me and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled on [the question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93937/how-to-display-clickable-features-from-geoserver-over-google-maps-v3-base) and it lead me to OpenLayers 2.1 Beginners Guide by Erik Hazzard.  It looks to be just what I need to figure out how to make a web map application.